# Image thumbnail in product images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

Hello I am working on a web page and would like to show my product to the customers somewhat like this

http://store.americanapparel.net/french-terry-s-s-kangaroo-pullover-hoody_fs424

I want my image to be shown and all other variants of the product image to be shown under the bigger image and all the effects as this. Can someone tell me how to achieve this? thanks

Comment: Have you tried something so far? Please, add to your question all the code you have already have so we can help you.

Comment: Here is a plugin that may help you: http://www.starplugins.com/cloudzoom/examples

Comment: I have tried but not able to do much with it.

Comment: Again, try to show us what have you tried. There are some plugins that gan help you: http://www.tutorialchip.com/jquery/15-useful-jquery-image-zoom-plugins/

Comment: Dont forget to at least accept my answer as I just went out of my way to code it for you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I would do it:

A little AngularJs

```
var demo = angular.module('demo', []);

demo.controller('demoCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.imgs = {};

  $scope.imgs.a = {
    'small': 'http://placehold.it/150x150/000000',
    'large': 'http://placehold.it/500x500/000000'
  };
  
  $scope.imgs.b = {
    'small': 'http://placehold.it/150x150/cccccc',
    'large': 'http://placehold.it/500x500/cccccc'
  };
  
  $scope.imgs.c = {
    'small': 'http://placehold.it/150x150/ffffff',
    'large': 'http://placehold.it/500x500/ffffff'
  };
  
  $scope.viewShowing = $scope.imgs.a.large;
  
  $scope.applyNewLargeView = function(largeViewUriString){
   $scope.viewShowing = largeViewUriString; 
  }

});
```

CSS

```
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  width: 500px;
}
.main,
.sub {
  display: block
}
.main > img {
  width: 100%;
}
.sub > img {
  width: 33%;
}
```

Jade markup

```
main(ng-app="demo", ng-controller="demoCtrl", class="container")
  .main
    img(ng-src="{{ viewShowing }} ")
  .sub
    img(ng-repeat="img in imgs", ng-click="applyNewLargeView(img.large)" ng-src="{{ img.small}}")
```

Heres the finished product:

http://codepen.io/nicholasabrams/pen/MwOMNR